# How to configure Electron Angular app with Vite

Tags: angular, electron, vite

I am trying to setup a new electron+angular project which uses Vite for bundling. Can someone provide a complete tutorial or article on how to setup such an application?

Electron has a Vite Plugin but I can't get it to work. https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/vite

Comment: Angular does't support vite out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

I [reviewed all Electron frameworks back in 2021](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/wiki/State-of-Electron-frameworks-%5BMay-2021%5D) and found that if you want an Electron app that uses Vite and Angular, you should check out [vite-electron-builder](https://github.com/cawa-93/vite-electron-builder).